# youtube-dl not working for all youtube videos

Tags: html, video, youtube

I use Youtube API to collect data, then I use `node.js` Youtube Downloader.
On the end I use video on classic html5 `<video>` tag.

In some reasons some video's work well some not.

I use this package on server part ->
https://www.npmjs.com/package/youtube-dl

```js
    if (request.url.search(/.nidza|.dzoni/g) != -1) {

        // file.serveFile('bad.html', 402, {}, request, response);
        const localVid = request.url.split("?vid=")
        console.log("videoID => ", localVid[1])
        console.log("Vule bule request.url., ", request.url)
        const addressLink = 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=' + localVid[1]
        const checkvideo = '../dist/videos/vule' + localVid[1] + '.mp4'

        try {
          if (fs.existsSync(checkvideo)) {
            // file exists
            console.log("skip...")
            response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
            response.end('[video-exist]');
             return;
          }
        } catch(err) {
          console.error(err)
        }

        const myPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

          var test = youtubedl(addressLink, ['--format=18'], { cwd: __dirname })
          try{
            resolve(test)
          } catch(err) {
            reject(err)
          }

        }).then((video) => {

          video.on('info', function(info) {
            console.log('Download started')
            console.log('filename: ' + info._filename)
            console.log('size: ' + info.size)
          })

          const videoName = '../dist/videos/vule' + localVid[1] + '.mp4';
          video.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(videoName, {
            flag: "w+"
          }))

        }).catch(function(err) {
          reject().than(()=>{
            console.log("Error in promise youtubedl => ", err)
          })
        });

        response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'})
        response.end(`VuleTube service version 0.3.1 \n
                      https://maximumroulette.com:3000 `)

      }
```

[Link for server node.js](https://github.com/zlatnaspirala/vue-typescript-starter/blob/master/vue-ts-starter/server/server-connector.js)

Error logon server side:

```sh
f an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)  
(node:23569) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
Request contains invalid range header:  [ '0', '' ]
Error: Range request present but invalid, might serve whole file instead
    at Server.respondNoGzip (/var/www/html/applications/vue-project/vue-typescript-starter/vue-ts-starter/server/node_modules/node-static/lib/node-static.js:297:23)
    at Server.respond (/var/www/html/applications/vue-project/vue-typescript-starter/vue-ts-starter/server/node_modules/node-static/lib/node-static.js:350:14)
    at /var/www/html/applications/vue-project/vue-typescript-starter/vue-ts-starter/server/node_modules/node-static/lib/node-static.js:146:22
    at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:166:5)
Range request exceeds file boundaries, goes until byte no 524287 against file size of 1312 bytes
Error: Range request present but invalid, might serve whole file instead
    at Server.respondNoGzip (/var/www/html/applications/vue-project/vue-typescript-starter/vue-ts-starter/server/node_modules/node-static/lib/node-static.js:297:23)
    at Server.respond (/var/www/html/applications/vue-project/vue-typescript-starter/vue-ts-starter/server/node_modules/node-static/lib/node-static.js:350:14)
    at /var/www/html/applications/vue-project/vue-typescript-starter/vue-ts-starter/server/node_modules/node-static/lib/node-static.js:64:22
    at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:166:5)
```

Any suggestions.

Comment: Please add whether are differences between a playable video and non-playable video - check the url, network tab of the browser, if those videos are available (*embed, pirvate, deleted, etc*).

Comment: are the video that do not play fast start?

Comment: What is `fast start` mean ? @szatmary

Comment: Location of of 'moov' box. If you dont know what this means, Google it. This is information you absolutely MUST know if you want to stream mp4 files.

Comment: OMG i found this https://www.xda-developers.com/github-warns-of-bans-for-users-still-distributing-youtube-dl/  Is youtube-dl ilegal ?

Comment: It's not illegal. The complaint was by RIAA (Record Industry of American Artists). If you don't use American music like Taylor Swift or Micheal Jackson then you don't fit their complaint. Also this has been fixed (YT-DL refuses to download such files)... PS: I am not promoting any downloading but if you keep it as friendly usage and not some dis-respectful & excessive pirating then you might just be okay.

Comment: I use it just like techical solution. I put logo "Developed with youtube" also i delete files after some time. There is no any redistribution even playing in ofline regime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some videos do not work because Youtube does not always expose their video's urls when requested.

Youtube-DL makes a request to `http://www.youtube.com/get_video_info?video_id=XXXX` (where `XXXX` is the video ID) and this returns a JSON text file which has a listing of file urls for the MP4 / webM / M4A, OGG etc, associated with the requested video upload.

For example:

(1) **Is working:** You can find `googlevideo.com` links (MP4 etc) mentioned inside the JSON
Pinocchio (trailer) : http://www.youtube.com/get_video_info?video_id=y8UDuUVwUzg

(2) **Not working:** You cannot find `googlevideo.com` links in this JSON (no video links to download)
Mirage (full film) : http://www.youtube.com/get_video_info?video_id=FTY-L-l3KN8

Comment: I need to try it . I will test `http://www.youtube.com/get_video_info?` on critical videos. I use always format -18 .....

Comment: I tested `youtube-dl -F` and there is no standard format for all resources. In first catch i will try to get info and then looks for right exist source. Thks

Comment: I had a chance to check again and saw that your [_"not working"_ link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P7d1H83IcjE) was actually a live-stream. The M3U8 link is mentioned in the video page's source code so try that if your app can play TS files.